# Runtime Wrapper Extension

Tags: scorm

I'm a beginner in the world of **`Scorm`**. I try to communicate between the SCO and the LMS via the API Wrapper. Where can I download `SCORM` Runtime Wrapper Extension Dreamweaver. I have not found.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options in the top five results on [Google](http://google.com). Why Don't you try one of those?

Comment: can you send me the link please?

Comment: Sure: https://www.google.com/?q=SCORM+Runtime+Wrapper+Extension+Dreamweaver - the top link is https://www.adobe.com/resources/elearning/extensions/dw_ud/scorm.html